# What's wrong with my CURL code? Stackoverflow's API is giving me suspicious character chain

Tags: php, api, curl

```
<?php
function get($get){
        $ch = curl_init("http://www.google.com/");
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
        echo    $output = curl_exec($ch);
}
get("stackoverflow");
```

[works fine](http://sandbox.phpcode.eu/g/7ec61.php)

However stackoverflow's API

```
<?php
function get($get){
        $ch = curl_init("http://api.$get.com/1.1/users/?filter=genesis&max=10000&min=5000");

        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
        echo    $output = curl_exec($ch);
}
get("stackoverflow");
```

[looks wrong](http://sandbox.phpcode.eu/g/dd881.php)

Is it bug of SO's API? Does this belong to Meta?

Comment: what about just using file_get_contents($url);

Comment: @yes123: same http://sandbox.phpcode.eu/g/edd86.php

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to add

```
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_ENCODING , "gzip");
```

to your code. API's response is gzip encoded

Comment: Did you looked at the headers from the SO API response? Things like `ContentEncoding:  gzip` and the like?